# AWS Amplify python backend auth with frontend auto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, amplify-auth-cognito

Since `withAuthenticator` helps handling the frontend portion of authentication, I wonder if there are still needs to add extra wrappers to python backend? The Lambda functions for the backend does not have public access. Also, there is no plan to provide external api calls to customer as well. Or, in another word, what components should be added to make the backend more secure?

(added withAuthenticator to the frontend, and tested the python backend without auth wrapper)